# `less` not able to display special characters

Tags: bash, terminal, utf-8, man, less

I stumbled upon bad special characters in some manpages:

> If your terminal is a "true" auto-margin terminal (it doesn▒<80><99>t allow the
>          last position on the screen to be updated without scrolling the screen)
>          consider using a version of your terminal▒<80><99>s termcap that has  automatic
>          margins  turned off. This will ensure an accurate and optimal update of
>          the screen in all circumstances. Most terminals nowadays  have  "magic"
>          margins  (automatic margins plus usable last column). This is the VT100
>          style type and perfectly suited for screen.  If all  you▒<80><99>ve  got  is  a [...]

I have done some research. `man` uses `$pager` as its display tool and this is set to `less` in my environment. So apparently `less` is not able to display the man pages's special characters.

My terminal (putty) is set to Utf-8, and `$LANG=en_US.UTF-8`. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 3):

See first if you have `LESSCHARSET` environment variable set.

```
echo $LESSCHARSET
```

If that is not `utf-8` already, then set it:

```
export LESSCHARSET="utf-8"
```

See if that helps. You may also try a pager called `most`, it's available at least on Debian/Ubuntu package repositories.

Answer (score 0):

Try another pager (such as `most`).

```
PAGER=most man command_name
```

or

```
man -P most command_name
```

or

```
man --pager=most command_name
```

to see whether it can display the apostrophes correctly.

It may be that the source file (if any) for the `man` page is bad, the tools for processing the `man` page (`*roff`) are handling the character incorrectly, or the object file (`cat` file) those tools create may be incorrect. On some systems, you can regenerate the `man` page object files.

Run `man` with one of these options (`-W`, `--where-cat` or `--location-cat`) to see where the `cat` file is located. Try renaming (rather than deleting - so you can put it back if necessary) the `cat` file so a new one gets generated.

You might try specifying the encoding to see if it helps. Try `UTF-8` and `UTF-16`, for example.

```
man -E UTF-8 command_name
```

or

```
man --encoding=UTF-8 command_name
```

Finally, run `mandb` to check the cache consistency.

Answer (score 0):

Try `-r` option to display raw characters, example:

> less -r file.txt